# Iterate over a range shell

Tags: shell, zsh

```
for a in bar
do
    for b in 1000000
    do
        montage -geometry 500 $a-$b-*-${0..20000..1000}.png \
        $a-$b-${0..20000..1000}-final.jpg
    done
done
```

I'm unable to get all the images with number `0 1000 2000 ... 20000` using `$(0..20000.1000)` .

Is there an other way in shell to do this?

Answer (score 3):

There must be no `$` before `{START..END..STEP}`

```
% echo -{0..20000..1000}-                                    
-0- -1000- -2000- -3000- -4000- -5000- -6000- -7000- -8000- -9000- -10000- -11000- -12000- -13000- -14000- -15000- -16000- -17000- -18000- -19000- -20000-
```

That being said, you need a loop to go over these numbers. The word containing a range is just replaced by its expansion. That means the command line is *not* called for each element alone, but for all of them together. It also means, that, even if you are using the same range twice, their expansion will not conveniently be combined.

Compare

```
% echo start a-{1..3}-b A-{1..3}-B end
start a-1-b a-2-b a-3-b A-1-B A-2-B A-3-B end
```

and

```
% for n in {1..3}; do echo start a-$n-b A-$n-B end; done
start a-1-b A-1-B end
start a-2-b A-2-B end
start a-3-b A-3-B end
```

So in your example instead of

```
montage -geometry 500 $a-$b-*-${0..20000..1000}.png \
    $a-$b-${0..20000..1000}-final.jpg
```

you probably want to do

```
for n in {0..20000..1000}; do
    montage -geometry 500 $a-$b-*-$n.png $a-$b-$n-final.jpg
done
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

file_names= ["a","b"]


ranges =  list(xrange(0, 20000, 1000))
l_s = list()
for f in range(0, len(file_names)):
    for a in range(0, len(ranges)):
        stringing = str(file_names[f]) + "--1000000-0-0-0-1-" + str(ranges[a]) + ".log.png"
        l_s.append(stringing)

    final = " ".join(l_s)
    foo = "montage -geometry 500 " + str(final) + " " + str(file_names[f])+ "-final.jpg"
    os.system(foo)
```

Comment: Python did the job for me.

Comment: I know you were the OP, but you asked for a shell solution, so answering with a Python one is not helpful to the next guy.